# how to reference the Type in the Concrete class of a generic class

Tags: c#, .net, generics, subtype

I found the following example, to which I have a follow up question.

[stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11034275/c-sharp-concrete-override-of-generic-class)

the existing code from the question is

```
 public interface IRepository<T> where T : EntityObject
 {
    RepositoryInstructionResult Add(T item);
    RepositoryInstructionResult Update(T item);
    RepositoryInstructionResult Delete(T item);
 }

 public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : EntityObject
 {
    virtual RepositoryInstructionResult Add(T item)
    { //implementation}
    virtual RepositoryInstructionResult Update(T item);
    { //implementation}
    virtual RepositoryInstructionResult Delete(T item);
    { //implementation}
  }

public class BarRepository : Repositorybase<Bar>
 {
    public override RepositoryInstructionResult Update(Bar item);
    {
       //Call base method if needed
       //Base.Update(item);

       //implement your custom logic here
    }
  }
```

what I would like to do is change the Update method to something like

```
public class BarRepository : Repositorybase<Bar>
 {
    // T is of Type Bar
    public override RepositoryInstructionResult Update(T item);
    {
       //implement your custom logic here
    }
  }
```

Question: is there a way to expose the generic type in `BarResposity : Repositorybase<Bar>`  to the methods in BarRepository?

looking for a better alternative to "search and replace" when building out the concrete class (eg make a copy of BarRespository as FooRepository and change all references from Bar to Foo). I would rather change the type in one place only.

(edit) Usage needs to remain as

```
var obj = new BarRepository();
```

Comment: If your type is `BarResposity : Repositorybase<Bar>`, then `T` has no meaning, you haven't defined it anywhere. There's no quick fix that would make copy/paste code work without editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit of a hack, but you *could* use a `using` alias to define the entity type:

```
 using MyType = Bar;

 public class BarRepository : Repositorybase<MyType>
 {
    public override RepositoryInstructionResult Update(MyType item);
    {
   
       return base.Update(item);
    }
  }
```

Now when you copy to `Foo.cs`, you can just change the using directive to

```
 using MyType = Foo;
```

But, I would look to try and reuse as much generic code as possible, as it's not clear at all what `MyType` is just by looking at the methods. There's nothing wrong with a find.replace to define a new repository type that customizes actions - you just want to keep the repeated to a minimum.

Comment: cool. definitely close to what I am looking for. will try this out.

Comment: this so worked. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: just for reference, this is the link to ms doc [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive#using-alias)... never would have found this on my own. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a note, if you're going to override all Add/Update/Delete anyways, you can make them as abstract in the RepositoryBase and then the vs suggestion is your friend:
[image]

and if there is shared logic between all of concrete classes you can put it in the abstract class and override abstract protected methods instead.

**edit:**
op asked for code that can do it.. well this should work.. but if you want a new concrete implementation, you'll have to create 2 classes now

```
public class BarRepository<T> : RepositoryBase<T> where T : Bar
{
    public override int Add(T item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public override int Update(T item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public override int Delete(T item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class BarRepository : BarRepository<Bar>
{

}
```

also, if classes are so similar that copy-paste and replace is enough, maybe logic shouldn't be in separate classes but in the generic class? could you give an example of 2 classes maybe?

edit 2: another dirty trick would be to use lambdas, though personally I don't know if I would do it:

```
public abstract class RepositoryBase<T>
{
    public Func<T, int> Add { get; protected set; }
    public Func<T, int> Update { get; protected set; }
    public Func<T, int> Delete { get; protected set; }
}
public class BarRepository : RepositoryBase<Bar>
{
    public BarRepository()
    {
        Add = i => 6;
        Update = i => 7;
        Delete = i => 8;
    }
}
```

Comment: that is one approach that works.
not what I am looking for though.
question is, is there a "code" approach to solving this.

fyi: I have also looked at code snippets and tt templates; these are also valid approaches similiar to the intellisense.

Comment: I added a code approach, but you'll have to declare 2 classes with it, also, if classes are so similar that copy-paste and replace is enough, maybe logic shouldn't be in separate classes but in the generic class? could you give an example of 2 classes maybe?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO any GENERIC repository is a waste of time, but if you decide to use it ,  what is wrong with this

```
public class BarRepository<T> : Repository<Bar> where T : class
{
    public override void Update(Bar item)
    {

    }
    
    public  void Update(T item)
    {
     
    }
}
```

UPDATE

It looks weird but since OP wants it , you can create this code too

```
public class BarRepository<T> : Repository<Bar> where T : Bar
{
    public override void Update(Bar item)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("it is Bar");
    }
    // T is of Type Bar
    public void Update(T item)
    {
          Console.WriteLine("it is T");
    }
}
```

tests

```
public class Bar { }
public class NoBar { }

var barRep= new BarRepository<Bar>();

barRep.Update(new Bar()); // "it is T"

var noBarRep= new BarRepository<NoBar>(); // ERROR!
```

UPDATE 2

since if you want

```
var rep = new BarRepository();

var result= rep.Update(new Bar());
```

you can do it the way you have done already

```
public class BarRepository : Repositorybase<Bar>
 {
    public override RepositoryInstructionResult Update(Bar item);
    {
   
       return base.Update(item);
    }
  }
```

PS

if you  are still  not satisfied,  look at the beginning of my answer and forget about the generic repositories. Use the custom ones as the most proffesional developes do.

Comment: `T` and `Bar` mean different things in this example, since `T` might be a descendent of `Bar`.

Comment: What I have been looking for is a class "declaration" like the one you have added, that says T is the type Bar.

Comment: I dont think this is valid...

```public class BarRepository<T> : Repository<T> where T : class of Bar
{
    public override void Update(Titem)
    {       }
}```

Comment: This seems to valid....

```public class BarRepository<T> : Repository<T> where T : Bar, new()
{     public override void Update(T item)     {       } 
}```

Comment: duh. works but doesnt. when creating an instance of BarRespository<T> need to pass Bar as T, which is what we are trying to avoid doing....
the above code means doing ```var obj = new BarRespository<Bar>()``` ; what is wanted is ```var obj = new BarRepository()```

Comment: I get where you are going with this; but this is looking like a "cant get there from here" type of problem. basically, BarRespository is a concrete class of the generic Repository<T>. without using reflection, there doesnt seem to be a way to use an abstract reference to the concrete type. and using reflection in this case is making the code overly complex.

Comment: @I am sorry, but I don't understand what do you mean. I offered you 3 variants already. All code was tested and working properly. What else do you want.

Comment: yes, the options you have suggested work, but are not an improvement on the original implementation.

Comment: I just don' t see what impovements you need. YOu have to post the real example, what you need and why it can  not be done with what you have now.